# JDBC, INSERT MULTIPLE records obtained from query, into other table

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jdbc, resultset

I need to insert multiple records into mysql database at once. What I am doing is `SELECT` on one table, from my application with Prepared statement. What I must do is to insert those results into one other temporary table.

```
String sqlquery = "select * from table1 where arg1 = ?";
PreparedStatement statement;
statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);


ArrayList<String>termlist = index.getTermList();
for (int i = 0; i < termlist.size(); i++) 
{
    String search = termlist.get(i);
    statement.setString(1,search);

    ResultSet rs1 = statement.executeQuery(); //
}
```

These sets might be big. What is the fastest way to insert this ResultSet somehow into my other table, after each iteration?

How to pass this resultsset to some stored procedure, if there is way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the database to do the work for you:

```
INSERT INTO othertable
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1
WHERE arg1 = ?
```

This way you don't have to send a copy of data to the database that already exists there.

Comment: Thanx Mark. Gosh this seems simple didnt come to my mind. So i just make this as prepared statement??? If i do it in this way, is it possible to, in case I did not have match with searchstring, somehow to keep reference to this searchstring? 
I mean if i do not do the ResultSet count???

Answer (score 0):

You could perform a single query if you pass a comma separated list of parameter values into a stored procedure and use an `IN (val1, val2, ...)` clause. Not sure what MySQL's limit is for the length of an IN clause.

Here's a [split](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648) implementation.